# Google Maps Fragment is Black

Tags: android, google-maps, bottom-sheet, supportmapfragment

I'm having this strange issue where google maps shows up black when using it inside a persistent `BottomSheet`. The same map fragment used in the `CoordinatorLayout` works perfectly fine.

Also using `app:liteMode="true"` works with the persistent bottom sheet.

The code is pretty simple

```xml
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

> Map added directly to CoordinatorLayout
> [image: Map added directly to CoordinatorLayout]

> Map added to BottomSheet
> [image: Map inside BottomSheet]

> NOTE: It works on my emulator with API26 fine but doesn't work on any other devices and emulators.

P.S. The search at the bottom is a Persistent BottomSheet